# Where was blood dripping from in Hacksaw Ridge's rope ladder?

Tags: plot-explanation, hacksaw-ridge

During the first climb of the platoon on [Hacksaw Ridge](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2119532/), blood drips on the soldiers. They conclude that the blood is from fallen fighters on top of the ridge.

However, **when they reach the top, there is no body up there dripping blood on them**.

Where did the blood come from? Was it soaked in the rope and dripping? Or is it a movie mistake?

Comment: I personally filed that under 'mistake,' but would have to watch it again to make sure the ropes weren't soaked in blood. However, I've seen enough of Andrew Garfield's hair to last me awhile, so someone else will have to take up that challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the AV Club's review](http://www.avclub.com/review/mel-gibsons-hacksaw-ridge-makes-gruesome-case-non--245202), the blood rain was

> the result of shelling against a nearby Japanese position

In other words, the Japanese soldiers were literally vaporized, and some of their remains, in liquid form, rained down on the Americans below.

Comment: Literally vaporization contradicts liquid form of Japs.